# How do I fix this authentication error in Ubuntu 20.04.1?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi

I prepared a new system of ubuntu 20.04.1 for raspberry pi and tried to run it on the raspberry pi for the first time. After I have logged in with the default password, the system forces me to change the password, I obeyed, only to find that the authentication error will occur directly afterwards, and the raspberry pi will be disconnected.

By the way, connect to the raspberry pi from my laptop through WIFI provided by the router which is connected to the raspberry pi using a cable.

I don't have a cable port on my laptop.

[image]

Comment: this error means that the password utility passwd cannot manipulate the token. The token here means the hash of the password that you specified. This can occur due to the inability to write a new hash to the config file, because:

- The program does not have permission to write to the / etc / shadow file;
- The file system is mounted read-only;
- Damage to the file system;
- There is no free space on the disk;
- The wrong authentication module is being used;
Try this: https://www.codevoila.com/post/26/fix-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-changing-user-password-in-ubuntu